# Replacing Overlapping Regex Patterns in Python

Tags: python, regex, replace, ttl

I am dealing with trying to make a `.ttl` file I was handed digestible. One of the issues is that the `rdfs:seeAlso` values are not sanitized and it breaks down downstream programs. What I mean by this is that there are links of the form:

```
rdfs:seeAlso prefix:value_(discipline)
```

In order to fix this, I need to precede particular characters with a `\`, per [the RDF 1.1 Turtle documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/turtle/#sec-escapes). Of the characters present, I need to escape the following:

```
_, ~, -, !, $, &, (, ), *, +, =, ?, #, %
```

At first I thought this would be easy and I began constructing a `re.sub()` pattern. I tried a number of potential solutions, but the closest I could get was with:

```
re.sub(pattern=r"(rdfs\:seeAlso)(.{0,}?)([\_\~\-\!\$\&\(\)\*\+\=\?\#\%]{1})(.{0,})", repl='\\1\\2\\\\\\3\\4', string=str_of_ttl_file)
```

The `(rdfs\:seeAlso)` component was added in order to prevent accidentally changing characters within strings that are instances of `rdfs:label` and `rdfs:comment` (i.e. any of the above characters in between `''` or `""`).

However, this has the drawback of only working for the first occurrence and results in:

```
rdfs:seeAlso prefix:value\_(discipline)
```

Where it should be

```
rdfs:seeAlso prefix:value\_\(discipline\)
```

Any help or guidance with this would be much appreciated!

EDIT 1: Instances of `rdfs:label` and `rdfs:comment` are strings that are between single (`'`) or double (`"`) quotes, such as:

```
rdfs:label "example-label"@en
```

Or

```
rdfs:comment "This_ is+ an $example$ comment where n&thing should be replaced."@en
```

The special characters there do not need to be replaced for Turtle to function and should therefore be left alone by the regular expression.

Comment: "rdfs:seeAlso" has none of the special characters. Unless the label or comment are defined so that they can include special characters, there is no need to exclude "rdfs:seeAlso" specifically: nothing in it would be escaped. If label or comment can contain special characters, you should mention that explicitly, and/or give a relevant example.

Comment: @9769953 Apologies, yes "rdfs:label" and "rdfs:comment" can contain special characters, and there may be additional properties in the future added that may also contain special characters, but they will always be in between quotes as I mentioned. I'll edit the post to be more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you don't have to escape characters inside `[...]` in your pattern (`-` should be last however, otherwise in will be recognized as range). This will make your code more readable. Then you can replace in a while loop and use a lookbehind to ensure that the character isn't already escaped:

```
import re

input_text = "rdfs:seeAlso prefix:value_(discipline)" 

pattern = re.compile(r"(rdfs:seeAlso.*?)(?<!\\)([_~!$&()*+=?#%-])")

repl_str = ''
while repl_str != input_text:
    repl_str = input_text
    input_text = re.sub(pattern, r'\1\\\2', repl_str)

print(input_text)
```

Note: using raw string for your replace pattern makes it much more readable

Output:

```
rdfs:seeAlso prefix:value\_\(discipline\)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should split checking if your string starts with `rdfs:seeAlso` and replacement.

```py
str_of_ttl_file = "rdfs:seeAlso prefix:value_(discipline)"

if str_of_ttl_file.startswith('rdfs:seeAlso'):
    str_of_ttl_file = re.sub(r'([_~!$&()*+=?#%-])', r'\\\1', str_of_ttl_file)

print(str_of_ttl_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution does it *without regular expressions*:

```
def escape(inputstr, chars_to_escape):
    translation_dict = {c: '\\' + c for c in chars_to_escape}
    translation_table = str.maketrans(translation_dict)
    return inputstr.translate(translation_table)

def conditionalTurtleReplace(inputstr):
    if inputstr.startswith('rdfs:seeAlso'):
        return escape(inputstr, r'_~-!$&()*+=?#%')
    else:
        return inputstr

str1 = 'rdfs:seeAlso prefix:value_(discipline)'
str2 = 'rdfs:label "example-label"@en'
str3 = 'rdfs:comment "This_ is+ an $example$ comment where n&thing should be replaced."@en'
print(conditionalTurtleReplace(str1))
# output: rdfs:seeAlso prefix:value\_\(discipline\)
print(conditionalTurtleReplace(str2))
# output: rdfs:label "example-label"@en
print(conditionalTurtleReplace(str3))
# output: rdfs:comment "This_ is+ an $example$ comment where n&thing should be replaced."@en
```